# I need to divide all the number in one column (A) with all the numbers in another column (B), except where the values of B is zero

Tags: r

All the columns are in one data frame and I need to divide A by B to get C, except for any value B equal to zero.
The output im looking for would look something like this:

```
A     B      C
25    4      6.25
5     0      5
10    2      5
7     1      7
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `ifelse` to return the values of 'A' where 'B' is 0 or return the value of `A/B`

```
df$C <- with(df, ifelse(B == 0, A, A/B))
```